# HttpURLConnection SocketTimeoutException is not working when timeout is set

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I want to set timeout for my requests in app if connection is slow(for example user drives to tunnel as some request is running in background).

I want to have 5 seconds timeout for each call. It will redirect him to special NoConnection screen. I set it to 5000(I think its in ms) I waited more than 30 seconds and no exception returned. If I set it for example to 10 it will return `SocketTimeoutException` and everything is working.

Code:

```
try{
    val con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    con.requestMethod = method
    con.connectTimeout = 5000
catch(e: IOException){
    if(e is SocketTimeoutException){
       throw OfflineError()
    }else{
       throw GenericError()
    }

}
```

Comment: Try setting both `con.connectTimeout()` and `con.readTimeout()`. Maybe the connection is established and stuck waiting for a response.

Comment: Yep this was problem